# Remove location Service from existing iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ibeacon

I have tried to find a answer for my question and I can't find one.

I have an app that today have Location service and remote notifications, and the customer now want to remove those features from the code all fine here. But we realized that the Location service and notifications still is present in the app settings and give the user the option to turn on and off a service that the app do not have any more. How to one remove location service and notifications from the app settings in iPhone? The code connected to this features is removed and I have checked the plist and can't find any trace of neither location service or notifications.

Comment: I forgot one thing, it's not possible to say to the user that they need to delete and reinstall the app

Comment: Are you talking about live app downloaded from App Store?

Comment: Yes. This app is live today and have Location Service and remote notifications, the new app that will be release should no longer have this services and I'm testing this app localy and in Settings -> app-name I still can see both notifications and location service

Comment: Please install fresh application by deleting the existing one & then see..

Comment: That is not an option

Comment: I mean you delete the development app from your device & then see the Location,Notification info in settings application..

Comment: If I delete the app from the device the location Service and notification service in settings is removed but not when I just updating the app. The problem is that I can't demand from the user to remove the app and then reinstall it to get rid of the services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible.   When you use CoreLocation, iOS is going to associate those permissions with the settings of your app.  As you have noted, updating the app at a later time to not use CoreLocation does not remove these settings.

Without an operating system change to iOS, I don't think there is any way to remove these from settings without uninstalling and reinstalling the app, which I understand is not an option to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks that sound like the conclusion I came to.